# Custom Alexa skills to control sensors

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Is it possible to make custom Alexa skills to control commands like enabling/disabling sensors or getting sensor statuses?

We are making an IoT smart home device that has sensors to measure proximity, light, temperature, moisture, motion.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: Yes it is possible.

You need to create a new Smart Home Skill. To do this:

- Create an Amazon Developer account
- In your developer console go to the section `ALEXA`
- `Get started` with `Alexa Skill Kit`
- `Create new Skill`
- And choose then under pre-built models `Smart Home`

But probably you should read a bit about Alexa and Smart Home Skills watch [this](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smarthome/understand-the-smart-home-skill-api.html) for more information about the topic.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the help. However, as much as I have read, I think custom skills would be required for it since smart home skills have a lot of limitations. Don't you think so?

Comment: I think this a bad idea because a custom skill need to be activated first so you need to say Alex, ask mySkill to activate the light that’s kind of difficulty for the user. A smart home skill is directly integrated in the Alexa smart home environment. But i don’t know your exactly use case.

Comment: Hey, thanks again. According to the documents, smart home skills work only with certain devices and for certain commands. If you want your own intents then you have to design a custom skill. Do you agree?